# SearchScope fetchRows vs fetchObjects (IBM FileNet CE API)

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, filenet-cpe

I've been using `SearchScope.fetchObjects()` method till this time, and then it just occurred to me that `fetchRows` might be the better choice in some cases (when you don't need metadata like class names, object stores etc). Something tells me it might be faster, but I didn't found any arguments about what method to use in which case, and why.

Here is [SearchScope](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/p8docs/v5r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/query/SearchScope.html) documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference in performance of `fetchRows()` and `fetchObjects()` is negligible in most cases. If you process significant volume of data and still are concerned about performance I suggest making a simple test.

The only reason for existence of `fetchRows()` is the possibility to query disparate object classes using `JOIN`.